# Unable to access or safely remove encrypted device

Tags: linux-mint, dd, usb-drive, external-hdd, cryptsetup

Details: I have a bootable encrypted HDD (running Linux mint). I have cryptsetup (2:2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1) installed on my main machine.

I can access the unencrypted partition of the 1TB HDD. The system prompts me for a password to access the encrypted partition, but after inputting the password I receive an message: "Unable to mount encrypted drive. Operation cancelled".

I try to safely remove the drive in the GUI and I get the error "Unable to stop drive. The drive is in use: Encrypted device is unlocked".

How can I access and mount the drive properly?

**fdisk -l for external HDD**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: EXTERNAL_USB    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BDD64F37-DBAC-4C63-9358-A34D406FECCB

Device       Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624    2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2549760 1000214527 997664768 475.7G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: 951.68 GiB, 1021862477824 bytes, 1995825152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgmint-root: 930.37 GiB, 998974160896 bytes, 1951121408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vgmint-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-92738e1a-3898-487a-8168-5a2596c561fa: 475.71 GiB, 510787584000 bytes, 997632000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: The fdisk information doesn't look too useful. How about `lsblk -f`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred because I used the GUI utilities which were not successful in mounting the drive as the vgname is same for the volumes in external HDD and the internal SSD. They are both bootable drives for linux mint and therefore their vgname is "vgmint".

**Warning: Renaming the vgname will make the bootable device unbootable. I was only able to revert this name change with a live USB (attempting to revert the name change on normal install will give an error that the vgname is same as another volume group)**

To access the encrypted external HDD:

1. `sudo dmsetup remove_all` to start the mounting process from scratch
2. Follow [these](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/11/16/how-to-mount-encrypted-lvm-logical-volume/) steps to manually mount the volume and make sure to rename the vgname:

- `sudo vgdisplay` to view details of volume groups
- `sudo pvdisplay -m` to view details of which physical drive is mapped to which volume group
- `sudo lvm vgrename <vg uuid of from vgdisplay> <new_name>` to rename volume group in the external HDD (this will make it unbootable)